# Inconsistent behaviour for action() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I do not know how to use this in order to always have **GET** parameters

Route is setup like

```
Route::controller('/test', TestController::class);
```

If I specify the `getIndex` function, it adds **GET** parameters

```
>>> action('TestController@getIndex', ['type' => '123'])
=> "http://localhost/test?type=123"
```

But if I specify anything but the `getIndex` function it does not add the parameters as **GET** variables

```
>>> action('TestController@getSuccess', ['type' => '123'])
=> "http://localhost/test/success/123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output of `php artisan routes --path=/test`

Some of the routes (like the one mapped to `getSuccess`) have [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters) and Laravel attempts to match the given parameter array to the route parameters.

Once all the query parameters are accounted for, any excess elements are converted into a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and appended to the final URL.